# Position background image at bottom CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position my background image to be center bottom, I know there is a `backgorund-position` property, however it does not change anything to me.

At the moment I made the image responsive but it's just not bottom.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    body {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        background: #2d8eb8 url("https://i.ibb.co/Cn1P5vk/bg.jpg") 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center bottom;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Also if possible, I would like to place the style in a  instead of the whole body, I can't manage to do it myself

Comment: you never make the body element position:fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `background-size: 100%` instead of using `cover` because `cover` will tend to cover the full width

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
html {height: 100%;}
body {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    background: #2d8eb8 url("https://i.ibb.co/Cn1P5vk/bg.jpg") 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work for this small example, I tried to implement this on my other project and failed. do you mind taking a look? it's all uploaded here: https://codepen.io/yarin177/pen/xxLxGja

Comment: sure.. I have fixed that in here https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/NWvWqmp?editors=1100  @yarinCohen

Comment: Glad to assist you :)

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again, but I noticed that on phones you can scroll to move the background? can it be made so a user wouldn't be able to move it?

Comment: I dont see any scrolls here can you send me the actual link

Comment: https://brawlhallacases.github.io/auth/page2/

notice how on phones you have the option to scroll

Comment: Add the following to your head tag 


`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Well, that kinda messes up bunch of things.. you can open this website again and see what it did

Comment: Add that in the start https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp  refer thos

Comment: You definitely gonna need to add responsive media queries for your webpage

Comment: Oh no, my nightmare, well thank you for the help :)